# Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression: {{value?}} | Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I'm running into trouble with showing the variable that is initialised asynchronously. I added the `?` in the template to catch the error that it would be undefined but it says the expression end unexpected.

```
@Component({
  template: `<div>{{value?}}</div>`
})

export class Component implements OnInit {
    value: number;

    constructor(private _service: Service) { }

    getValue() {
        this._service.getValue().subscribe(data => this.value = data);
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message you get without the `?`

Comment: I don't get an error message then. It just does not show the number, not even when the http request is resolved.

Comment: Try `this._service.getValue().subscribe(data => console.log(data));` to see if the expected data is received.

Comment: Ah, this does print the correct value. Turned out I messed up in the subscribe by adding a second assignment the wrong way. Like this: .subscribe(data => this.value = data['first'], data => this.secondValue = data['second']))

Comment: So this issue is fixed?

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your case you can use the variable directly without the Elvis operator:

```
@Component({
  template: `<div>{{value}}</div>`
})
```

It's useful when you try to access property of a variable gotten asynchronously. For example:

```
@Component({
  template: `<div>{{value?.someProperty}}</div>`
})
```

Comment: It loads and doesn't error, but it doesn't show the value after it is initialised.

Comment: What is the content of the `getValue` method?

Comment: getValue() {
        return this.http.get(VALUE_URL)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

Comment: And you request is successfully executed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by the "says the expression end unexpected" but the `?` is just invalid at this position.